# Need some help on Serial Port Transmission

Tags: c, serial-port, microcontroller, 8051

i'm currently using DS89C450 MCU on Keil C51 Programming.

I have an Infrared Receiver attached to P3^2 which is the falling edge trigger. Whenever I press a key on the remote control, it will trigger the interrupt and save it into the xdata X or Y (bit by bit then byte by byte for 500 bytes).

I'm trying to transmit the data bit (either '1' or '0') from the buffer to the hyperterminal via Serial Port. However, I do not get any data displayed when I press the remote control.

Can anyone expert tell me why and how do i get it to work?

The program is here:

http://pastebin.com/hpAw2ipH

Comment: Is the data you are transmitting ASCII encoded, and is it cleaned for non-appropriate serial control characters? HyperTerminal shows and reacts to these, so it's usually not the most appropriate program for displaying binary data. Try googling for a binary serial port monitor instead.

Comment: @sonicwave Erm, no the transmitting data are only binary '1' and '0'. Maybe, i should use MTK instead?

Comment: Give [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) a try.  If you are stuck with HyperTerminal, you could convert the data to an ASCII hex representation for debugging.

Comment: @GregInozemtsev Hi. When i connect the RealTerm, all it shows is "00000000" all '0'. Maybe i didn't know how to set the settings of the RealmTerm.

Comment: Have you looked at the signal at either the input capture pin or the serial port output with a scope?  Has your timing been verified?

Comment: Also, when setting up your terminal, make sure the baud rate is correct, as is the parity and stop bits, and if you aren't using RTS/CTS then you need to turn off Flow Control.  I can't tell from your code what your expected settings are as they aren't commented.

Comment: @AdamCasey My Baud Rate is 9600, Parity: None, Data bits: 8bits,

Stop bit :1 bit, Hardware Flow Control: None.

Comment: divide the problem in half.  make a copy of the project, remove all of the ir code, leave yourself with only code that initializes the serial port and sends characters to the host, the character 'U' is good because it is 0x55 and produces a square wave on the serial port (esp if you have a scope you can use to check the signal).  Dont use any interrupts, disable all of that, simply poll the transmitter status register and send characters, or just count to a few ten thousand in a loop then write to the uart tx register again.

Comment: If you cannot send characters to the host that way then adding more code and complicating it with interrupts is not going to change it.

Comment: When you have reached the end of your rope with the uart not working, then make another copy of the original project, strip out all the uart code, only have the input gpio pin on, do not use interrupts, poll the pin, hopefully you have an led somewhere and know how to set that (should have been your first program on that board) on and off.  When you press the remote, for example maybe change the state of the led.  Or have a tight loop that sets the led output pin to match the ir remote input pin.  (If you have spare leds just connect it directly to the ir device)

Comment: granted, yes setting up for interrupt may be different than setting up for general purpose input I/O.  maybe not depending on your device, you probably still have to do some sort of config to set it as an I/O input.  If you cant see the input change states either with a scope, or by using an led, or eventually using the uart to indicate what is going on, adding the complication of interrupts and handlers is not going to make it easier.

Comment: putty makes for a good serial terminal program as well.  while sending out 0x55s or some character I guess it doesnt matter, change the baud rate setting up and down through all of the possible choices.  VERY often there is a divide by two or four or eight in the clock tree that you didnt know about and you think you set for 9600 but you really set for 4800 or 2400.  by far the best is to use an oscilloscope and just look at the signal and measure the bit periods to see what it is actually transmitting at or if it is even transmitting.

Comment: @dwelch I have tried removing all the codes except the initalising the serial port and sending the character 'U' at 9600 baud rate, none parity bit, 1 stop bit, 8 bit data bits and none hardware flow control. It was shown on the hyper terminal perfectly fine.

http://pastebin.com/BC7MFtr6

Comment: So you have something that works on that end, get the IR and gpio side of the program working and then put the two together. Or just build upon the working uart code as you try to get the ir code to work.

Comment: @dwelch I have thought of creating a case function to convert the data to ASCII so it could be displayed on the hyperterminal.

Comment: exactly, find some way to show yourself what the microcontroller is seeing on that interface, from there you can decide what to do with that data on that interface.  Perhaps the data wasnt exactly what you thought it was going to be, with more information you can decide how to handle it now that you have a better picture of what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google "Terminal by br@y", it can show serial comms in HEX. Most UARTs cannot send a single bit, rather they will send a character of N bits, usually 7 or 8, with start/stop/parity bits (8-bits, no parity, 1 stop bit being the universal default). It can make life easier to encode data as ASCII, perhaps even with start/stop characters, so you know when you're getting real data.

For even more detail, use an oscilloscope, BusPirate or LogicSniffer (from DangerousPrototypes.com) to sniff the communications data.